# find all ordered triples of distinct positive integers i, j, and k less than or equal to a given integer n that sum to a given integer s

Tags: clojure, sicp

this is the exercise 2.41 in SICP
I have wrote this naive version myself:

```
(defn sum-three [n s]
  (for [i (range n)
        j (range n)
        k (range n)
        :when (and (= s (+ i j k))
                   (< 1 k j i n))]
    [i j k]))
```

The question is: is this considered idiomatic in clojure? And how can I optimize this piece of code? since it takes forever to compute`(sum-three 500 500)`

Also, how can I have this function take an extra argument to specify number of integer to compute the sum? So instead of sum of three, It should handle more general case like sum of two, sum of four or sum of five etc.

I suppose this cannot be achieved by using `for` loop? not sure how to add i j k binding dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Update: The fully optimized version is `sum-c-opt` at the bottom.)*

I'd say it is idiomatic, if not the fastest way to do it while staying idiomatic. Well, perhaps using `==` in place of `=` when the inputs are known to be numbers would be more idiomatic (NB. these are *not* entirely equivalent on numbers; it doesn't matter here though.)

As a first optimization pass, you could start the ranges higher up and replace `=` with the number-specific `==`:

```
(defn sum-three [n s]
  (for [k (range n)
        j (range (inc k) n)
        i (range (inc j) n)
        :when (== s (+ i j k))]
    [i j k]))
```

(Changed ordering of the bindings since you want the smallest number last.)

As for making the number of integers a parameter, here's one approach:

```
(defn sum-c [c n s]
  (letfn [(go [c n s b]
            (if (zero? c)
            [[]]
            (for [i  (range b n)
                  is (go (dec c) n (- s i) (inc i))
                  :when (== s (apply + i is))]
              (conj is i))))]
    (go c n s 0)))

;; from the REPL:
user=> (sum-c 3 6 10)
([5 4 1] [5 3 2])
user=> (sum-c 3 7 10)
([6 4 0] [6 3 1] [5 4 1] [5 3 2])
```

*Update:* Rather spoils the exercise to use it, but [math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics) provides a `combinations` function which is tailor-made to solve this problem:

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as c])

(c/combinations (range 10) 3)
;=> all combinations of 3 distinct numbers less than 10;
;   will be returned as lists, but in fact will also be distinct
;   as sets, so no (0 1 2) / (2 1 0) "duplicates modulo ordering";
;   it also so happens that the individual lists will maintain the
;   relative ordering of elements from the input, although the docs
;   don't guarantee this
```

`filter` the output appropriately.

*A further update:* Thinking through the way `sum-c` above works gives one a further optimization idea. The point of the inner `go` function inside `sum-c` was to produce a seq of tuples summing up to a certain target value (its initial target minus the value of `i` at the current iteration in the `for` comprehension); yet we still validate the sums of the tuples returned from the recursive calls to `go` as if we were unsure whether they actually do their job.

Instead, we can make sure that the tuples produced are the correct ones *by construction*:

```
(defn sum-c-opt [c n s]
  (let [m (max 0 (- s (* (dec c) (dec n))))]
    (if (>= m n)
      ()
      (letfn [(go [c s t]
                (if (zero? c)
                  (list t)
                  (mapcat #(go (dec c) (- s %) (conj t %))
                          (range (max (inc (peek t))
                                      (- s (* (dec c) (dec n)))) 
                                 (min n (inc s))))))]
        (mapcat #(go (dec c) (- s %) (list %)) (range m n))))))
```

This version returns the tuples as lists so as to preserve the expected ordering of results while maintaining code structure which is natural given this approach. You can convert them to vectors with a `map vec` pass.

For small values of the arguments, this will actually be slower than `sum-c`, but for larger values, it is much faster:

```
user> (time (last (sum-c-opt 3 500 500)))
"Elapsed time: 88.110716 msecs"
(168 167 165)
user> (time (last (sum-c 3 500 500)))
"Elapsed time: 13792.312323 msecs"
[168 167 165]
```

And just for added assurance that it does the same thing (beyond inductively proving correctness in both cases):

```
; NB. this illustrates Clojure's notion of equality as applied
;     to vectors and lists
user> (= (sum-c 3 100 100) (sum-c-opt 3 100 100))
true
user> (= (sum-c 4 50 50) (sum-c-opt 4 50 50))
true
```

Comment: The code looks pretty cool. Thanks! However I've been looking at it for half hours but still can't understand how it works. Can you explain a bit about the recursion part? I'm still kind of new to clojure and lisp :)

Comment: `c` is the number of integers per result tuple. `go` is a function which returns a seq of all tuples comprising `c` integers from `(range b n)` which sum up to `s`. It accomplishes this by looping over the integers from this range and, for each such integer `i`, calling itself recursively to produce all tuples of `(dec c)` integers from `(range (inc i) n)` (starting the range higher to avoid some work) which sum up to `(- s i)`, then `conj`ing the `i` onto each such tuple (the sum thereby being brought up to `s`). The base case is a seq comprising a single empty tuple for `(== c 0)`.

Comment: The proof of correctness for `sum-c` would be inductive, with the most convenient approach starting with a base case of `(== c 1)` (since the `[[]]` value returned from `go` makes the whole thing work, but doesn't really fit the description of `go` given above -- there is no `i` at that level of recursion and the sum of the only tuple returned is just `0`). Thinking through the proof is useful in this case, as it gives one an idea for a further optimization resulting in a version performing just the work which is really necessary. I've updated the answer to include the fully optimized version.

Comment: (That's fully optimized from "forever" down to "88 msecs" ;-).)

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution! Learned a lot from it

Answer (score 1):

for is a macro so it's hard to extend your nice idiomatic answer to cover the general case. Fortunately clojure.math.combinatorics provides the cartesian-product function that will produce all the combinations of the sets of numbers. Which reduces the problem to filter the combinations:

```
(ns hello.core
  (:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo]))

(defn sum-three [n s i]
  (filter #(= s (reduce + %))
          (apply combo/cartesian-product (repeat i (range 1 (inc n)))))) 

hello.core> (sum-three 7 10 3)
((1 2 7) (1 3 6) (1 4 5) (1 5 4) (1 6 3) (1 7 2) (2 1 7) 
 (2 2 6) (2 3 5) (2 4 4) (2 5 3) (2 6 2) (2 7 1) (3 1 6) 
 (3 2 5) (3 3 4) (3 4 3) (3 5 2) (3 6 1) (4 1 5) (4 2 4) 
 (4 3 3) (4 4 2) (4 5 1) (5 1 4) (5 2 3) (5 3 2) (5 4 1) 
 (6 1 3) (6 2 2) (6 3 1) (7 1 2) (7 2 1))
```

assuming that order matters in the answers that is

Comment: Of course this generates the entire Cartesian product, which is more work than necessary for this task. Better to use `c.m.c/combinations`. Added that to my answer, but please go ahead and edit it in here if you agree. (Also, I'd use `==` in the `filter` predicate.)

Comment: if order matters, as mentioned in the question title then the Cartesian product is correct, if order does not matter then combinations is correct.

Comment: Oh, I see, I wasn't sure what you meant there. The question specifies `(< 1 k j i n)`, output tuples being of the form `[i j k]`. To get all orderings, you could use `mapcat`, `permutations` and `combinations` together, sticking the `filter` between `permutations` and `combinations`, to avoid computing the entire Cartesian product. Something like `(mapcat permutations (filter #(== s (apply + %)) (combinations (range n) c))`.

Comment: NB. I mean the question text specifies this (the function given supposedly produces the correct output); I take it that the expected triples are ordered in the sense that each contains a bunch of numbers in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

For making your existing code parameterized you can use `reduce`.This code shows a pattern that can be used where you want to paramterize the number of cases of a `for` macro usage.

Your code without using `for` macro (using only functions) would be:

```
(defn sum-three [n s]
  (mapcat (fn [i]
            (mapcat (fn [j]
                      (filter (fn [[i j k]]
                                (and (= s (+ i j k))
                                     (< 1 k j i n)))
                              (map (fn [k] [i j k]) (range n))))
                    (range n)))
          (range n)))
```

The pattern is visible, there is inner most map which is covered by outer mapcat and so on and you want to paramterize the nesting level, hence:

```
(defn sum-c [c n s]
  ((reduce (fn [s _]
             (fn [& i] (mapcat #(apply s (concat i [%])) (range n))))
           (fn [& i] (filter #(and (= s (apply + %))
                                  (apply < 1 (reverse %)))
                            (map #(concat i [%]) (range n))))
           (range (dec c)))))
```